# Makefile executing shell command hangs

Tags: shell, awk, sed, makefile, grep

I am facing an issue with my makefile, as it hangs when I issue `make debug`.

Here is the directory's tree:

```
├── makefile
└── src
    └── config
        ├── config_192_168_3_226.h
        └── config.h
```

And here is the content of the three files:

makefile:

```
BOARD :=  $(shell awk '/BOARD_VERS/{print $NF}' $(echo "src/config/$(grep -oP "(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")" src/config/config.h)"))

.PHONY: debug

# Debug rule
debug:
    @echo 'BOARD        :' $(BOARD)
```

config.h:

```
#ifndef _CONFIG_H
#define _CONFIG_H

#include "config_192_168_3_226.h"

#endif /* _CONFIG_H */
```

config_192_168_3_226.h:

```
#define BOARD_VERS      V1
```

The command I use to set **BOARD** variable is working correctly, but it does not when issued inside my makefile.

`awk '/BOARD_VERS/{print $NF}' $(echo "src/config/$(grep -oP "(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")" src/config/config.h)")`

What is wrong with my makefile? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is special to make.  If you want to pass it to the shell, in *BOTH* a recipe *AND* in a `$(shell ...)` function, you have to escape it as `$$`.

So here:

```
BOARD :=  $(shell awk '/BOARD_VERS/{print $NF}' $(echo "src/config/$(grep -oP "(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")" src/config/config.h)"))
```

The `$(echo ...)` is seen by make as a make variable with a long, bizarre name and expands to the empty string.  So basically you're passing no arguments to `awk` which means that it's reading stdin to operate on, which is why it appears to hang.

You have to double all the `$` that are not make variables:

```
BOARD :=  $(shell awk '/BOARD_VERS/{print $$NF}' $$(echo "src/config/$$(grep -oP "(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")" src/config/config.h)"))
```